# How to add new content when a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I made a design with ajax, jquery, mysql and checkbox in php. It is like that :

There is box with checkboxes. And there is another box which is empty. When you checked a checkbox in first box, information about that checkbox will be displayed in empty box. I did it and work good.But when you clicked another checkbox, information about first you clicked dissappear and only current selection is displayed. That is to say, I want to add new selection on old ones. Also how can I delete information in second box when I unchecked a checkbox. Thank you.

Here is HTML  code :

```
<div id="first_box"> 
  <label class='checkbox'>
     <input type='checkbox' id=1> 
         First checkbox
  </label>
  <label class='checkbox'>
     <input type='checkbox' id=2> 
         Second checkbox
  </label>
  <label class='checkbox'>
     <input type='checkbox' id=3> 
         Third checkbox
  </label>
</div>
<div id="second_box"> </div>
```

Here is jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#first_box input:checkbox").change(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) { 

       $.post("/here/is/url", { strID:$(this).attr("id"), strState:"1" },
        function(data) {
         $("#second_box").html(data);
       });

  } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'here/is/url/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { strID:$(this).attr("id"), strState:"0" }
      });
  }
 });    


});
```

Here is the php code for ajax request :

```
$strID    = $_POST['strID'];
$strState = $_POST['strState'];

    if ($strState) { //if checkbox is clicked

        //I fetch data about checkbox which is clicked
        $infos = $this->info_model->get_info_from_checkbox_id($strID);

        foreach ($infos as $info) {
            echo "<label class='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>".$info->information .
                "</label>"; 
        }
    } else {  // if it is unchecked

         // I do not know how to delete 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add new selection on old ones.

you can use `append()` instead of `html()` which replaces the content:

```
$("#second_box").append(data);
```

> how can I delete information in second box when I unchecked a checkbox.

you can use `empty()` which removes the contents of the selected element:

```
$("#second_box").empty();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, there was no need to write this long code. Answer was simple. That works for adding on old ones.

Comment: @kalaba2003 you are welcome, no worries, i had copied/pasted them :).

Comment: Thank you for your interest. empty() works but it empties all box. I want to delete info only which checkbox is clicked. Is there any way?

Comment: @kalaba2003 you are welcome, yes there is a way, it depends how the markup and returned contents are structured. you can use remove() method.

Comment: Thank you really. I dealt with problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do more on the client-side. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRqgg/1/) for a demo.

```
<div id="first_box"> 
  <label class='checkbox'>
    <input data-url="url1" data-id="1" type="checkbox"> First checkbox
  </label>

  <label class='checkbox'>
    <input data-url="url2" data-id="2" type="checkbox" > Second checkbox
  </label>

  <label class='checkbox'>
    <input data-url="url3" data-id="3" type="checkbox"> Third checkbox
  </label>

</div>

<div id="second_box"></div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first_box input:checkbox").change(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (already_loaded()) {
            update_visibility();
        } else {
            load();
        }

        // END -- Functions

        function already_loaded() {
            return $this.data("loaded");
        }

        function is_loading() {
            return $this.data("loading");
        }

        function load() {
            if (!is_loading()) {
                $this.data("loading", true);
                var id = $this.data("id");
                $.post("url", { // or use $this.data("url") if you want individual URLs
                    strId: id
                }, function(data) {
                    $this.data("loaded", true);
                    $this.data("is_loading", false);
                    $("#second_box").append(data);
                    update_visibility();
                });
            }
        }

        function is_checked() {
            return $this.is(":checked");
        }

        function update_visibility() {
            var $info = $("#info-" + $this.data("id"));
            if (is_checked()) {
                $info.show();
            }
            else {
                $info.hide();
            }
        }
    });
    $("#first_box input:checkbox").data("loaded", false);
    $("#first_box input:checkbox").data("loading", false);
});​
```